# Is there a Windows file format with <CR>-separated records (without <LF> characters)?

Tags: windows-7, linux, carriage-return

Today a file was extracted on a Windows system, Windows 7 to be exact, and ftp'd to a Unix system. The application that processes the file deliberately failed, because the file had one line in it, even though its multiple records were separated by `<CR>`. The file was extracted from an Access application.

Is this format some kind of short-cut Windows uses? I'm used to record terminators that are either `<CR><LF>` or `<LF>`.

I know how to fix the problem; I'm just curious as to this file format I have not seen before.

Just to be clear. This file had no `<LF>` paired with each `<CR>`. I have also re-checked. Running dos2unix on this file does not change the one line into multiple records (lines).

Comment: Just FYI, MacOS used to use CR line endings before OS X, but it doesn't seem like that's where your file comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<CR>` coding for lines was used by several older systems, including Apple II and most importantly, Mac OS (through version 9, the last classic Mac system before the introduction of OS-X).  Use on Windows is not normal.  Most likely an Access option to export to (old) Macintosh was in effect for the extraction.

Comment: The last time this file was extracted it was on Windows XP SP 3. The version of the Access application has not changed. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check, You use FTP in Binary mode. Otherwise FTP protocol try to convert line separation from source OS to target.

Comment: Thanks. We'll try setting SecureFx in ascii conversion mode.