# Is there a mac2unix utility?

Tags: windows, mac

This question is directly related to another [question](https://superuser.com/questions/687050/is-there-a-windows-file-format-with-cr-separated-records-without-lf-charact) I asked here.

Linux/Unix have nice utilities `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` for conversion of text files between the two OSs. Are there similar utilities for Macs and Linux?

Comment: As @Spiff said, you probably don't need anything Mac specific, as MacOS X is UNIX underneath. Are you using Mac OS 9 or previous? What version of MacOS/System do you need this for?

Comment: The old MacOS use \r as line break. The current version of Microsoft Excel of Mac still use \r as line break when saving a text file. For these files, run "mac2unix" or "dos2unix -c Mac " to convert the line break into \n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` do exactly, but my guess is that it changes text file line endings from dos format to Unix format and back.  Macs (as of OS X) and Unix use the same line-endings (line-feed, '\n') so if that's what you're worrying about, you don't need to do anything to move files back and forth.

Using `dos2unix -c Mac mac_file` turns the Mac formatted file into a Unix formatted file.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I don't think `-c mac` is correct. I think that's a holdover from the 80's and 90's when classic Mac OS (System 1 through Mac OS 9) text files had bare CRs (carriage returns) as line endings). Mac OS X uses Unix line endings (bare LFs; linefeeds).

Comment: @Eric be careful with `\n`. In many contexts, it's technically a "newline" which means that it will be replaced with the correct OS-dependent line ending sequence. So on Mac OS X and other Unixes, it will be replaced with an ASCII LF (linefeed) character 0x0a, but on Windows it may be replaced with a CRLF (0x0d0a). Back in classic Mac OS (Mac OS 9 and earlier), the `\n` sequence in MacPerl would be replaced by classic Mac OS's CR (just an ASCII 0x0d carriage return) line ending.

Comment: I just tried dos2unix -c Mac on a Centos 6 system, and it turned the "Mac" file into a Linux file. That is it removed the `<CR>` and replaced it with an `<LF>` character. For a regular Windows file `<CR><LF>`, it stripped only the `<CR>`.

Comment: Whoever edited this to include `-c Mac`, Thank you. That's what I had to do to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

OS X uses LF line endings and UTF-8-encoded files without a BOM  in most places like other Unix platforms. CR line endings were mainly used in Mac OS 9 and earlier.

For example AppleScripts and text copied from some views in Finder and iTunes still use CR line endings. You can convert CR line endings to LF with `mac2unix`, `dos2unix -c mac`, or `tr \\r \\n`. `dos2unix` and `mac2unix` can be installed with `brew install dos2unix`.

If you need to convert Windows files to the format used by OS X, you can use `dos2unix`. It converts CRLF line endings to LF. If a file is encoded as UTF-16, it also converts the file to UTF-8, and if a file has a BOM, it removes it.